# Running JAR file issue: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=216

Tags: java, windows, jar

I am currently encountering a really weird problem. I have a JAR application, and it was working fine before. But recently I got an issue when running it, this is what I got from the console:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=216. This version of %1 is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information and then contact the software publisher
```

The Windows version is Windows Server 2012 R2, and the Java SE Development Kit version is 1.8.0.60. I have already searched around on the Internet and have not had any concrete ideas yet. So what are the possible reasons that can cause this weird issue? Any helps or suggestions will be really appreciated.

Thank you very much!

Comment: check that you are using the correct 32/64 bit version